# How to create an endpoint with Tapir in Scala with multiple Schemas

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, http4s, tapir

I’m just heading an issue when I’m trying to create an endpoint with multiple bodies shape.

My model looks like this:

```
sealed trait FileExampleTrait {
  def kind: String
}

case class FileExampleOne(name: String, length: Int) extends FileExampleTrait {
  override def kind: String = “one”
}

case class FileExampleTwo(name: String) extends FileExampleTrait {
  override def kind: String = “two”
}

case class FileExampleResponse(message: String)
```

And I’m trying to create this endpoint:

```
val fileExample = baseEndpoint.post
    .in(“example”)
    .in(jsonBody[FileExampleTrait])
    .out(jsonBody[FileExampleResponse])
    .summary(“something”)
    .description(“something”)
```

The implementation of the endpoint looks like this:

```
private val fileExample = toAkkaRoute(jwtConsumer, errorHandler)(
    FileApi.fileExample, { (scope: RequestScope, input: (FileExampleTrait)) =>
      print(scope)
      input match {
        case FileExampleOne(name, _) => Future.successful(FileExampleResponse(name).asRight)
        case FileExampleTwo(name) => Future.successful(FileExampleResponse(name).asRight)
      }
    }
  )
```

This is just an example on what I’m trying to create. I added the schema derivation based on this:

```
  val sOne = Schema.derived[FileExampleOne]
  val sTwo = Schema.derived[FileExampleTwo]
  implicit val sExampleTrait: Schema[FileExampleTrait] =
    Schema.oneOfUsingField[FileExampleTrait, String](_.kind, _.toString)(“one” -> sOne, “two” -> sTwo)
```

I created a test for trying the endpoint based on Akka HTTP:

```
   test(“Example test”) {
    new Fixture() {
      val request = FileExampleOne(“name”, 1)
      Post(s”/api/v1/files/example”, jsonEntity(request)).withHeaders(requestHeaders) ~> wrappedRoute ~> check {
        response should be(successful)
        contentType shouldEqual ContentTypes.`application/json`
      }
    }
  }
```

The error I’m getting is the following:

```
Response error: {“code”:400,“message”:“Invalid value for: body (No constructor for type FileExampleTrait, JObject(List((name,JString(name)), (length,JInt(1)))))“}
```

I was following [this](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/schemas.html#sealed-traits-coproducts) documentation.

Comment: Don't you need to use `in(oneOfBody(..))`? Just a guess as I'm more familiar with different output types, not sure what input supports.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's because a trait doesn't have a constructor as indicated in the error itself. I think I see where you're going, you want to try parsing the body as one of the traits subclasses. So imagine you have this type/class hierarchy:

```
        T // parent trait
       / \
     C1  C2  // class 1, etc...
    /
  C3
```

Now you want to deserialize some JSON into trait `T`, you need to define your custom behavior, like "First try converting into C3, if failed, try converting to C2, if failed again, try converting to C1", and you'll get your `T` value. Now depending on the JSON library you use, the implementation might differ, see the [documentation](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/json.html) by softwaremill to get more information about how to deal with JSONs in tapir, and if you use Play Json, I can recommend:

```scala
object FileExampleOne {
  implicit val reader: Reads[FileExampleOne] = Json.reads
}

object FileExampleTwo {
  implicit val reader: Reads[FileExampleTwo] = Json.reads
}

object FileExampleTrait {
  implicit val reads: Reads[FileExampleTrait] = json => {
    json.validate[FileExampleOne] orElse json.validate[FileExampleTwo]
  }
}
```

You can see it running on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zBU0NnGnTPCJjkyr9sfqQA). And based on the [tapir documentations](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/customtypes.html), you need a `Codec` for your types, and one of the approaches to create your coded for JSON, is using one of tapir's supported libraries (circe, Play Json, ...).

Comment: Ah! I see, I'm currently using json4s but there is not much documentation about how to implement it, do you know what I can do?

Comment: @FedericoPortillo I’m not much familiar with json4s, but I’ll take a look for sure and update the answer if I found the approach.